# Calculate first value based on condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series

I have the following table `ticks`

| datetime | lowest_tick | tick_lower |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-01 00:02:00 | 204406 | 204306 |
| 2022-10-01 00:03:00 | 204525 | 204425 |
| 2022-10-01 00:04:00 | 204414 | 204314 |
| 2022-10-01 00:05:00 | 204200 | 204100 |
| 2022-10-01 00:06:00 | 204220 | 204120 |
| 2022-10-01 00:07:00 | 204120 | 204020 |

What I want to get is to show the first value `tick_lower_position` for `tick_lower` when `tick_lower <= lowest_tick`

So the resulting table should look like this

| datetime | lowest_tick | tick_lower | tick_lower_position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-01 00:02:00 | 204406 | 204306 | 204306 |
| 2022-10-01 00:03:00 | 204525 | 204425 | 204306 |
| 2022-10-01 00:04:00 | 204487 | 204387 | 204306 |
| 2022-10-01 00:05:00 | 204200 | 204100 | 204100 |
| 2022-10-01 00:06:00 | 204220 | 204120 | 204100 |
| 2022-10-01 00:07:00 | 204120 | 204020 | 204100 |

So far, I have tried to apply the solution provided by @the-impaler for other data.

```
select y.*, first_value(tick_lower) 
  over(partition by g order by datetime) as tick_lower_position
from (
  select x.*, sum(i) over(order by datetime) as g
  from (
    select t.*, case when lowest_tick <
      lag(tick_lower) over(order by datetime) 
      then 1 else 0 end as i
    from t
  ) x
) y
```

But this solution doesn't work for the current example.
As you may see in this example on [db<>fidle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ixHnUVIb) I got the wrong value in the 3rd row. `tick_lower_position` in the 3rd row still should be equal to 204306

Comment: Why is `204100` the bottom right value?  Isn't `204020` less than `204120` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen because `204100` is less than `204120`

Comment: Please explain your objective properly.

Comment: `What I want to get is to show the first value tick_lower_position for tick_lower when tick_lower <= lowest_tick` ... please edit this text to reflect the lag, if that is really your logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem (from what I gather from the vague description and comments) does not lend itself naturally to pure SQL. Seems like a case for a procedural solution:

Create this function once:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func()
  RETURNS TABLE (datetime timestamp, lowest_tick int, tick_lower int, tick_lower_position int)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   r  tbl;  -- use table type as row variable
   _tick_lower_position int;
BEGIN
   FOR r IN
      SELECT * FROM tbl t ORDER BY t.datetime
   LOOP
      IF r.lowest_tick > _tick_lower_position THEN
        -- do nothing
      ELSE
         _tick_lower_position := CASE WHEN r.tick_lower <= r.lowest_tick THEN r.tick_lower END;
      END IF;

      RETURN QUERY
      SELECT r.*, _tick_lower_position;  -- output row
   END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

Then call:

```
SELECT * FROM my_func();
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kvAOeXF-)

I let `tick_lower_position` default to `NULL` if your cited condition `tick_lower <= lowest_tick` is not met.

Comment: This is incredible!
Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, but you might be able to just use `MIN()` as a window function along with a `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT *, MIN(CASE WHEN tick_lower < lowest_tick THEN tick_lower END)
              OVER (ORDER BY datetime) AS tick_lower_position
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY datetime;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! 
Unfortunately, the provided solution does not meet the desired result.
[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RQJtkzVc)

Comment: Please edit your question and clearly explain your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

The query you tried is almost there you just need another layer getting  `least()` prior tick_lower_position and current tick_lower. See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/N__pLNp3):

```
select z.datetime    
     , z.lowest_tick 
     , z.tick_lower 
     , least(lag(tlp) over(), tick_lower) tick_lower_position 
  from ( select y.*
              , first_value(tick_lower) over(partition by g order by datetime) as tlp
           from ( select x.*, sum(i) over(order by datetime) as g
                    from ( select ticks.*
                                , case when lowest_tick < lag(tick_lower) over(order by datetime) 
                                       then 1 else 0 end as i
                             from ticks 
                         ) x
                ) y
        ) z;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
However, tick_lower_position for the last row should be equal to 204100 but in your demo it is equal to 204020